¿como configurar websocket con pusher angular y laravel echo no veo los eventos en console.log?
Estoy tratando de implementar un websocket simple al parecer tengo todo bien ya que logro emitir los eventos y en el panel de pusher se estan registro los mensajes y eventos. Si voy a Debug Console del panel de pusher veo esto:
API message
Channel: private-notificacions, Event: NotificationSent
02:39:12
{
  "notification": {
    "message": "Usuario creado: ",
    "user_id": 1
  }
}

Entonces estoy recibiendo el evento pero en consola.log de angular no veo que me imprima nada aca ni errores ni nada. El service donde implemente el websocket con pusher es:
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
import Pusher from 'pusher-js';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class LiveNotificationsService {
  public echo!: Echo;
  public channel: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    const token = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
    console.log(token);
    if (!token) {
      console.error(
        'Token no encontrado. Asegúrate de que el usuario esté autenticado.'
      );
      return;
    }

    (window as any).Pusher = Pusher;

    this.echo = new Echo({
      broadcaster: 'pusher',
      key: 'my key',
      cluster: 'mt1',
      forceTLS: true,
      authEndpoint: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/broadcasting/auth',
      auth: {
        headers: {
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
        },
      },
    });
  }

  listenForNotifications(callback: (notification: any) => void) {
    const userId = 1;

    this.echo
      .private(`notifications.${userId}`)
      .listen('NotificationSent', (data: any) => {
        //aca este console.log no arroja nada
        console.log(data);
        callback(data.notification);
      });
  }
}

En el componente igual eh agregado un console.log() para ver que pasa:
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.notificationService.listenForNotifications((notification) => {
    //aqui tampoco muestra nada aunque el evento se ah procesado en pusher o al menos eso parece en el panel
      console.log(`Notificación recibida: ${JSON.stringify(notification)}`);

    });
  }

mientras que en laravel tengo el evento
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast; 
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class NotificationSent implements ShouldBroadcast // Implementar ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $notification;
    public $userId;

    public function __construct($notification, $userId)
    {
        $this->notification = $notification;
        $this->userId = $userId;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        Log::info("Evento de notificación transmitido.");
        return new PrivateChannel('notifications.' . $this->userId);
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'NotificationSent';
    }
}

su channels.php
Broadcast::channel('notifications.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});

el broadcasting.php
'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                // 'cluster' => 'mt1',
                // 'host' => env('PUSHER_HOST') ?: 'api-' . env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER', 'mt1') . '.pusher.com',
                'port' => env('PUSHER_PORT', 443),
                'scheme' => env('PUSHER_SCHEME', 'https'),
                'encrypted' => true,
                'useTLS' => env('PUSHER_SCHEME', 'https') === 'https',


            ],
            'client_options' => [
                // Guzzle client options: https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html
            ],
        ],

y asi emito el evento
event(new NotificationSent($notification, 1));

sinceramente eh estado varias horas en esto sin poder resolverlo no entiendo que podria estar mal

private-notificacions.Events.NotificationSent ?
